# Help with Lagrange multiplier in to prove Geometric-Arithmetic Inequality

Tags: analysis, lagrange-multiplier, means

I have to prove the inequality of inequality of arithmetic and geometric means using the Lagrange multipliers. The book I am using (Wendell Fleming) give  me the next instructions:
$$f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R} $$
If $x = x^1x^2x^3...x^n$

$$f(x)=x^1·x^2·...·x^n ; M=\{(x): x^1+x^2+...x^n=1; x^i>0, \forall i\}$$
 -Show that $f(x) \leq n^{-n}$ with equality if $x^1=x^2=...x^n=n^{-1} $
If I prove that, the exercise is easy, but it also give a hint.

[Hint]=First prove that $f(x)$ has an absolute maximum on M. Apply the multiplier rule for $log(f)$ which has a maximum at the same point where $f$ has.

My problem is that I dont understand why the hint works, if i prove it, why it implies that $f(x) \leq n^{-n}$. And why $log (f)$ has a maximum at the same point that f.

Thanks if you can help me with this.

Comment: The thing about $\log(f)$ is simple: if you apply any increasing function to a function, all the minima and maxima are preserved. This trick is common, for example when minimizing the Euclidean distance we will often instead minimize its square (removing the square root) to simplify algebra/calculus.

Comment: Jmm I did't know that, but it does not change the restriction M?

Comment: No, you're only modifying the objective function, not the domain. You're not free to modify the domain of course.

Comment: But I can do that in every case? I am thinking in apply $log$ to $sin(x)$ and when I do that the maximum becomes 0...

Comment: The value at the maximizer in general changes. The position of the maximizer does not. (Of course you can't apply $\log$ to $\sin(x)$ because of domain problems.) This also doesn't always do you any good. Here the point of it is that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}$ is a function of $n-1$ variables but $\frac{\partial \log(f)}{\partial x_i}$ is a function of only one variable. This greatly simplifies the Lagrange multiplier equations.

Answer (score 1):

We need to prove that
$$\frac{x_1+x_2+...+x_n}{n}\geq \sqrt[n]{x_1x_2...x_n}$$ for non-negatives $x_i$.

Indeed, for $x_1x_2...x_n=0$ our inequality is obvious

and since our inequality is homogeneous, we can assume that $x_1x_2...x_n=1.$

Indeed, let $x_1x_2...x_n=k$, where $k>0$.

Now, let $x_i'=\sqrt[n]kx_i$ for all our $i$ and we obtain $x_1'x_2'...x_n'=1$,

but the inequality is not changed:
$$\frac{x_1'+x_2'+...+x_n'}{n}\geq \sqrt[n]{x_1'x_2'...x_n'}.$$

Thus, we can rewrite $x_i'$ like $x_i$ again and we need to prove that 
$$x_1+x_2+...+x_n\geq n.$$
Let $$f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n,\lambda)=x_1+x_2+...+x_n-n+\lambda\left(\prod\limits_{i=1}^nx_i-1\right).$$
The domain of $f$ is a compact $C$, where
$$C=\{(x_1,x_2,...,x_n,\lambda)|x_i\geq0,\lambda\in\mathbb R\}$$ and $f$ is a continuous function on $C$.

Thus, $f$ gets on $C$ the minimal value, which happens on the boundary of $C$, which is true,

or when for all $i$ $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}=0.$$
In this case we obtain $$1+\lambda\prod\limits_{k\neq i}x_k=0$$ or
$$x_i+\lambda\prod_{i=1}^nx_i=0,$$
which gives $x_1=x_2=...=x_n$ and since $\prod\limits_{i=1}^nx_i=1$, we got an unique critical point:
$$(1,1,...,1),$$
for which our inequality is obviously true.

Done!

Comment: The homogeneity approach is nice but I wouldn't advise using it at this level at least not without considerable elaboration.

Comment: @Ian Why? What do you mean? I am ready to explain how it works.

Comment: I'm just saying that it is not clear to a typical multivariable calculus student that you can assume without loss of generality that $\prod_{i=1}^n x_i=1$. And it doesn't *really* help you all that much, compared to just taking the gradients of $\log \prod_{i=1}^n x_i$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$ and setting them parallel.

Comment: @Ian I added something. What do you think?

Comment: Now it's perfect. I realize this is exactly what homogeneity means, but someone like the OP is probably not already familiar with the notion, and it can be a bit difficult to look up (because the word is terribly overloaded).

Answer (score 0):

For a given
$$
\sum_{k=1}^nx_k\tag1
$$
we wish to maximize
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\log(x_k)\tag2
$$
That is, for every variation so that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\color{#C00}{1}\,\delta x_k=0\tag3
$$
we want to have
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\color{#C00}{\frac1{x_k}}\,\delta x_k=0\tag4
$$
$\color{#C00}{\frac1{x_k}}$ is orthogonal to all variations that $\color{#C00}{1}$ is. That means that they are parallel. That is, there is a $\lambda$ so that
$$
\color{#C00}{\frac1{x_k}}=\lambda\cdot\color{#C00}{1}\tag5
$$
This means that to maximize $(2)$ under the constancy of $(1)$, we need $x_k=\frac1\lambda$ (a constant).

In all boundary cases, the product is $0$, so we know the maximum is an interior critical point.